# Why does the MailDefinition class require a System.Web.UI.Control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mailmessage

When creating a MailMessage object by calling the "CreateMailMessage" method on the MailDefinition class, the third parameter is an object of type System.Web.UI.Control.

```
MailDefinition mail = new MailDefinition();

ListDictionary replacements = new ListDictionary();
replacements.Add("<%myname%>", "John");

mail.BodyFileName = "~/App_Data/Emails/SomeEmail.txt";
mail.From = "me@example.com";
mail.Subject = "Hello";

MailMessage message = mail.CreateMailMessage("example@example.com,", replacements, );
```

Why is that?
And in the case that I don't have an object of that type, what should I pass instead?  Just a new Control object?

```
Control control = new Control();
```

**UPDATE**

I would highly recommend using [Razor](http://razorengine.codeplex.com/) to build email templates.  It has great syntax, works great, and doesn't have any weird dependencies!

Comment: Why aren't you using MailMessage message = new MailMessage()?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually you just pass `this` as the control.

```
MailMessage message = mail.CreateMailMessage("example@example.com,", replacements, this);
```

As for the reason why, [here is what MSDN says:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0002kwb2.aspx)

> The owner parameter indicates which control is the parent of the MailDefinition control. It determines which directory to search for the text file specified in the BodyFileName property.

Comment: And what if I'm not running this from an ASPX page, but from an APP_CODE class?

Comment: Then you need to pass in a reference to the current control into the code that is creating the mail message.

Answer (score 3):

The **CreateMailMessage** function internally uses the specified **Control** to query its **AppRelativeTemplateSourceDirectory** property and its **OpenFile** method to read the contents of the body (specified in the **BodyFileName** property of the **MailDefinition**).

Seems poor design and unnecessary tight coupling for me.

Comment: Indeed! But with the advent of the Razor templating engine, it doesn't really matter anymore :P http://razorengine.codeplex.com/ in case you've been living under a rock :)

Comment: @JohnBubriski Can I use ***RazorEngine*** in _ASP.NET_ **WebForms** application ?

Answer (score 2):

You can also just do this:

```
MailMessage message = this.Mail.CreateMailMessage("no-reply@example.com", dictionary, new System.Web.UI.Control());
```

Answer (score 1):

I have been using `new LiteralControl()` for the 3rd parameter because my messages are being sent from a Workflow.  It works.  But I do not have an answer for "Why".

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may not need to use the MailDefinition class at all if you're not binding to any controls.  To simply send an email over smtp, you should use a System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient with a System.Net.Mail.MailMessage.

Comment: Basically, I'm using the MailDefinition class for its replacement abilities.

Comment: Razor engine IMO is the new best practice way.